# Does assigning a point to Skeleton Mastery apply the benefits to current Skeletons?

Tags: diablo-ii

I've been wondering for a while; if I have say 8 skeletons active and I place a point into Raise Skeleton or Skeleton Mastery, will my currently active Skeletons gain the benefits, or do I need to re-raise my 8 skeletons for them to be at their maximum potential?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The skeletons have the attributes from your skill levels at the time they were cast.  So if you increase skeleton mastery, you will need to resummon your army.  Similarly, if you encounter a skill shrine, you should resummon them and they will retain the attributes of the +2 to all skills until they die.

[Source](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/370600-/57042100)

[Source](http://diablo.incgamers.com/forums/archive/index.php/t-225143.html)

Comment: I thought this would be the case. Interesting idea with the shrine; this tactic could even be useful for equipping an item with high +master and/or +skeleton and then swapping back to your original equipment.

Comment: @Marty Wallace Yes, that works. Just note, that if you switch weapons and your *Raise Skeletons* skill drops (so that your number of skeletons also drop), any additional skeletons will die. Weapon swapping is used frequently for this kind of stuff. Barbarians usually have +3 Warcry swords on their weapon switch to boost Battle-Orders and the other warcries.

Comment: @Marty-Wallace that's a very common tactic among Necromancers. A lot of Minion Masters just wear swap to +magic find skills once they summon there army, despite losing a  few skeletons in the process.

Comment: How did you find out about this? I always assumed the skill levels did apply to previously summoned minions...