# Do Iron Golems get the benefits of Summon Resist and Golem Mastery without being resummoned?

Tags: diablo-ii

This question is closely related to [one of my previous](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/24163/does-assigning-a-point-to-skeleton-mastery-apply-the-benefits-to-current-skeleto) but with a small twist.

So I've learned that applying points to Skeleton Mastery or similar **will not** affect my current skeletons. This is fine, because they're cheap to resummon.

I'm concerned about using decent items for my Iron Golem when taking the above into consideration. It seems flawed to me that the Iron Golem takes into account the same rules as the other Golems or Skeletons as it's a permanent summon (until killed). It could survive through me putting 10 points on Golem Mastery / Iron Golem / Summon Resist and still be the same strength this way, or rapidly become too inferior to survive as I progress because I can't increase its strength as I go.

Is there any chance that the developers were aware of this and the Iron Golem does in fact become stronger as you place points into these skills?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best way to be safe is just exit the game and get back in.  You will still have your iron golem, but with whatever skills/stats you have at the instant of getting into the game.

Comment: That doesn't seem logical - aren't the stats of the Iron Golem saved and reloaded? Can't imagine that they'd only save the stats the the item gave them.

Comment: Au contraire, the moment of entering a game would be the only time, where it would make sense to re-evaluate current skills of the Necromancer. At least in light of the Information you already had, that in-game minions properties are determined at the time of their creation. Have a look here: http://www.mannm.org/d2library/faqtoids/minions_eng.html#ig